# Is there an option to make LuaJIT do bounds checking?

Tags: lua, luajit

LuaJIT knows the C types it defines, and the lengths of the arrays, but it doesn't check the bounds:

```
ffi = require("ffi")

ten_ints = ffi.typeof("int [10]")
p1 = ten_ints()
print(ffi.sizeof(p1))  -- 40


var_ints = ffi.typeof("int [?]")
p2 = ffi.new(var_ints, 10)
print(ffi.sizeof(p2)) -- 40

p1[1000000] = 1 -- segfault
p2[1000000] = 1 -- segfault
```

Is there a way to make it do that, or is my only choice to write wrappers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: There is no way, you'll have to write/find your own wrapper.

Here is the explanation from [luajit.org](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_semantics.html)

> No Hand-holding!
>
> [...] The FFI library provides no memory safety, unlike regular
>   Lua code. It will happily allow you to dereference a NULL pointer, to
>   access arrays out of bounds or to misdeclare C functions. If you make
>   a mistake, your application might crash, just like equivalent C code
>   would. This behavior is inevitable, since the goal is to provide full
>   interoperability with C code. Adding extra safety measures, like
>   bounds checks, would be futile. [...] Likewise there's no way to
>   infer the valid range of indexes for a returned pointer. Again: the
>   FFI library is a low-level library.

Comment: *Adding extra safety measures, like bounds checks, would be futile.* -- what if I just define C structs for efficiency, and never call C? Anyway, thanks for the answer!